# Accelerometer data analysis

Tags: python, android, accelerometer, data-analysis

I would like to know if there are some libraries/algorithms/techniques (python, if at all possible) that help to extract features from accelerometer data (extracted from and android phone, btw), like periodicity of movements, energy of acceleration and the like. Has anyone done this kind of task before?

Thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about android but a lot of work has been done on Python/Symbain Accelerometer stuff.
You can find a link [here](http://www.mobilenin.com/pys60/menu.htm)